# Split string after x characters and whitespace

Tags: c#, string, loops

having a bit of a brain melt here and could do with some help on the logic for solving this issue.

im basically going to be creating images that are just text based on a user input.

Image width is fixed, so i need to parse the text so it all fits on the image, but i need to make sure that i only split on a whitespace and not break up words.

like this

```
after X amount of characters split string on last whitespace.
then after the next X amount of characters repeat.
```

The only way i can think of doing this is by looping through the text to find the last whitepace before X characters (if x is not a whitespace), splitting the string. and then repeating.

Can anyone think of a more elegant solution or is this probably the best way?

Comment: What is "X characters"? The max. number of chars that will fit on the image given the font you're using?

Comment: Yes X is the max number of characters that will fit on one line given image size and font size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A loop is certainly the way to go.  The algorithm you describe should work fine.  This can be done quite elegantly using an iterator block.  Read more about iterator blocks and the `yield return` construct [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx). You could also make the method into an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) so that it would look something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> NewSplit(this string @this, int lineLength) {
    var currentString = string.Empty;
    var currentWord = string.Empty;

    foreach(var c in @this)
    {
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {
            if(currentString.Length + currentWord.Length > lineLength)
            {
                yield return currentString;
                currentString = string.Empty;
            }
            currentString += c + currentWord;
            currentWord = string.Empty;
            continue;
        }
        currentWord += c;
    };
    // The loop might have exited without flushing the last string and word
    yield return currentString; 
    yield return currentWord;
}
```

Then, this can be invoked like the normal `Split` method:

```
myString.NewSplit(10);
```

One of the benefits of iterator blocks is that they allow you to perform logic after an element is returned (the logic right after the `yield return` statements).  This allows the programmer to write the logic the way he or she is probably thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this which works for a single split

```
public static string SplitByCountAndWhiteSpace(this string str, int length)
{
    var words = str.Split(' ');

    var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        strBuilder.Append($"{word} ");

        if (strBuilder.Length >= length)
            break;
    }

    return strBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**